# @RequestParam value converted to lower case

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

I've a simple controller containing a request param like:

```
@RequestParam(required = false) String name
```

Now I also have mockmvc test containing:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/hello/greet")
    .param("name", "Marcel"))
```

In the logging I see it seems the request param is passed through correctly:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = GET
  Request URI = /rest/hello/greet
   Parameters = {name=[Marcel]}
```

However in my controller the request param comes in in lowercase..

```
@Get(path = "/greet", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> greet(@RequestParam(required = false) String name) {
    logger.info("greet called with name: {}", name);
```

It prints `greet called with name: marcel`.
Also - obviously - when passing this argument to other service it is passed as lowercase.

It's a very simple Spring Boot application so I wonder why this request param is coming in in lowercase.

Comment: Check for servlet filters or some AOP around the controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue some `Converter<String, String>` was in application context which was causing this issue.